# Geometry nodes zipper problem

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I am making a procedural zipper and i am quite far already.
The only problem i am having is that when i draw a curve on the surface in the lower half of the object, the orientation of the teeth are getting messed up. It has to do with the curve tilt, if I reverse the tilt of the curves the problem flips to the upper half.
Does anyone have a solution?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice application!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have done everything right so far, only when generating the rotation you would have to use the *Tangents* of the curves instead of their *Normals*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are my hero. I have spend a lot of time trying to figure this out. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! Great project by the way and well built! I recently built something similar, but for garments created in *Marvelous Designer* and then imported into *Blender*. ...but haven't finished it yet because I find the questions here on BSE much more interesting ;-)

Comment: Thats sounds really cool, i am also trying to make a whole series of textile tools like stitches, zippers and buttons for example. It is fantastic that we can make our lives easy now with geonodes. Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: Is it possible to share the blend file for beginners to see how such a thing is setup?